# Looking for a hint on the following integration problem

Tags: real-analysis

> Let f(x) be continuous on [0,1]. Calculate $\lim_{n \to \infty} n\int_0^1 x^n f(x)dx$.

What immediately jumps out at me is how close $\frac{x^nf(x)}{\frac{1}{n}}$ looks to a derivative, i.e. if I only had the function $$\frac{(x+\frac{1}{n})^nf(x+\frac{1}{n})-x^nf(x)}{\frac{1}{n}}$$ inside the integrand, then I could answer the question with $1^nf(1)-0^nf(0)=f(1)$. So I am at a dead end down this path.

I've also tried using the Lebesgue DCT by wondering whether the series of functions $nx^nf(x)\to 0$ pointwise on $[0,1)$ since $f(x)$ is continuous and thus bounded on $[0,1]$.

Another attempt involved trying to use the second MVT, but that doesn't succeed, either, since I do not know beforehand that the value $k \in [0,1]$ such that $$n\int_0^1 x^n f(x)dx=f(k)\int_0^k nx^ndx$$ is actually $k=1$. Any hint would be appreciated!

Comment: *Hint:* $\displaystyle \frac{n}{n+1} \int_0^1 (n+1)x^n f(x)\,dx = \frac{n}{n+1} \int_0^1 f(x)\,d(x^{n+1}) = \frac{n}{n+1} \int_0^1 f(\sqrt[n+1]{x})\,dx$

Comment: That's right - I actually attempted something similar to this approach using $u=x^n$ when I should have used $u=x^{n+1}$. So close! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some hints: $\int_0^1 nx^n\,dx\to1$ and $\int_0^a nx^n\,dx\to0$ as $n\to\infty$, for any $0\le a<1$.

Comment: Would this be in line with the MVT like I did in my last attempt written above? I'm not sure how to proceed from here.

Comment: The point of my hints are these, in plain language rather than in mathematese: The function $nx^n$ has total “weight” very close to 1 as $n$ grows big, and almost all of that “weight” is concentrated near $x=1$. So your integral is computing a weighted average of $f$, with almost all of the weight concentrated around $x=1$. *Of course* that is going to get you $f(1)$, almost – meaning exactly, in the limit. The answer by @OliverOloa is a good way to translate that insight into a rigorous proof.

Answer (score 2):

Estimate $\int_0^1 nx^n \left(f(x)-f(1)\right) dx$ when $n \to \infty$, using the preceding hints.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution (if you have learned about functionals):

Set $\{x^k | k\geq 0\}$ is a fundamental set in $C[0, 1]$.

If we define functional $\Lambda_n(f)=n\int_0^1 x^n f(x) dx$ for every $n\in\mathbb N$, it is easy to calculate $\lim_{n\to\infty}\Lambda_n(x^k)=\lim_{n\to\infty} n\int_0^1 x^n x^k dx=\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n}{n+k+1}=1$.

(Notice: $\Lambda_n$ is corectly defined, linear and bounded: $\|\Lambda_n\|\leq 1$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$).

Therefore,
$\Lambda_n(a_k x^k+\dots+a_1 x+a_0)=a_k+\dots+a_1+a_0$.

If we define functional $\Lambda(f)=f(1)$ (which is linear and bounded!) , it is easy to conclude that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\Lambda_n(f)=\Lambda(f)$ on fundamental set.

Therefore, by $Banach-Steinhaus$ theorem we can conclude that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\Lambda_n(f)=\Lambda(f)$ on $C[0,1]$, or $\lim_{n\to\infty} n\int_0^1 x^n f(x) dx=f(1)$, for every $f\in C[0,1]$.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a rough outline of one proof (the same as suggested above, essentially):

1. Let $\epsilon>0$.
2. Choose $1>\delta>0$ so that $f(x)<f(1)+\epsilon$ for all $x\in[\delta,1]$.
3. Write
   $$
   \int_0^1 n x^n f(x)\,dx=
   \underbrace{\int_0^\delta n x^n f(x)\,dx}_A+
   \underbrace{\int_\delta^1 n x^n f(x)\,dx}_B
   $$
4. Using the fact that $|f|$ is bounded on $[0,\delta]$, show that $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} |A|=0$.
5. Show that $\limsup\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}B\le f(1)+\epsilon$.
6. As $\epsilon$ was arbitrary, use 3., 4., and 5. to infer that $$\limsup\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_0^1 nx^nf(x)\,dx\le f(1).$$
7. In a similar manner, show that 
   $$\liminf\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_0^1 nx^nf(x)\,dx\ge f(1).$$