# Limit $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{0}^{1} n x^n f(x) dx $

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits, uniform-convergence

I am unable to solve this limit of integral asked in a quiz and so looking for help here.

> Question : Let $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. Then what is the following limit:
> $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{0}^{1} n x^n f(x) dx $. Give the reasons.

If $n {x}^n f(x) $ was uniformly convegent then $\lim_{n \to \infty }$ could be taken inside the integral  but there is not enough information regarding the behaviour of $f(x)$ to check for uniform convergence.

So, Kindly tell how should I proceed.

Thanks!!

Comment: Use the substitution $u = x^{n+1}$

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/864442/42969  and https://math.stackexchange.com/q/128823/42969 – all found [with Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Clim_%7Bn%20%5Cto%20%5Cinfty%7D%20%5Cint_%7B0%7D%5E%7B1%7D%20n%20x%5En%20f(x)%20dx%24&p=1)